# Negative unack in RabbitMQ

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, bunny

Can someone explain this to me?

[image]

Stack is:
RabbitMQ, Sneakers, Ruby, Bunny

Comment: Somehow you have more jobs ready than there are in the system. I think you broke something. Can you reproduce this? It could be a bug in RabbitMQ you've discovered.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a management UI problem, [see this bug](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/issues/296)

The problem has been fixed in the last versions.

The version `3.6.7` is [around the corner](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/tag/rabbitmq_v3_6_7_milestone3), you can try with it.